# Html Textarea Input error: Request Failed Invalid Text value .A text field contains invalid data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, jsom, html-form-web-part

My form contains the html input "Textarea" tag .And when the user enters the data in textarea input-box and submit the form to save his info SharePoint list he is facing the below error .Can any one help me in knowing the issue and how can I solve this issue

```
<textarea id="txt12" rows="14" cols="150" maxlength="80050"></textarea>
```

> **Error**:Request Failed Invalid Text value .A text field contains invalid data .Please check the value and try again undefined

Comment: are you logging this field?

Comment: NO.I am not logging the field

Comment: What column type is the textarea value being written to?  Single Line of Text columns can only store 255 characters.  You might need to change the target column to a type of 'Multiple lines of text'